# Perl GD Image size in bytes

Tags: perl, size, gd

How can I get the size of the image I am creating in bytes using the GD module?
Sample code:

```
$newImage->copy($sourceImg,0,0,0,0,$width,$height);
open(IMG,">$outputImgName") || die "can't open $outputImgName";
binmode IMG;
print IMG $newImage->png;
close IMG;
```

I need the size of the "newImage", I am saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're writing the file to disk, just use the [`-s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) file operator:

```
my $size = -s $outputImgName;
print "Size is $size\n";
```